# How to solve search Title which does not open the actual description in another activity?

Tags: java, android

I made a string array list in String.xml; If I type a Title name in the searchbar, it indexes to display actual typed result.

But the problem I have now is if I click the searched title result so as to open as "description" in a newActivity it will instead open another tile's description which is placed as first in the string-array.

My question is, what am I supposed to do to make it open the correct description for the title result?

This is the `String.xml`:

```html
    <string-array name="array_titles">
        <item>Every second I spend with you is a moment from God to be thankful for. You are everything that makes me smile, rejoice and dream for a better tomorrow. </item>
        <item>Whenever I look into your eyes, I see the promise of a better tomorrow. I am blessed to have you with me every morning. </item>
        <item>May your dream come true, may your financial dreams begin to come true this week. Love. </item>
    </string-array>


    <string-array name="array_lyrics">
        <item>Wishes for Lovers</item> <item>Wishes for Lovers</item> <item>Wishes for Lovers</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="newbrandDesc">
       <item>Every second I spend with you is a moment from God to be thankful for. You are everything that makes me smile, rejoice and dream for a better tomorrow.</item>
       <item>Whenever I look into your eyes, I see the promise of a better tomorrow. I am blessed to have you with me every morning.</item>
       <item>May your dream come true, may your financial dreams begin to come true this week. Love.</item>
    </string-array>
```

This is the `MainActivity.java`:

```js
        //Listview icons for song titles in position
        icon = new int[]{R.drawable.list1,R.drawable.list1,R.drawable.list1};

        mRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        title = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_titles));
        //listview descriptions for songs in position
        description = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_lyrics));
        //listview NewDescriptions (NewActivity) for songs in position
        newDesc = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.newbrandDesc));

        for (int i = 0; i< title.size(); i++){
            Model model =new Model(title.get(i), description.get(i), newDesc.get(i), icon[i]);
            //bind all strings in an array
            arrayList.add(model);
        }

        //pass result to listview class
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, arrayList);

        //bind the adapter to the listview class
        mRecyclerview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

This is the adapter:

```js
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> implements Filterable {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Model> models, filterList;  // this array list create a list of array which parameter define in our class
    CustomFilter filter;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> models) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.models = models;
        this.filterList = models;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null); //this line inflate our row


        return new MyHolder(view); //this will return our view to holder class
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder myHolder, int i) {

        myHolder.mTitle.setText(models.get(i).getTitle()); //here is position
        myHolder.mDesc.setText(models.get(i).getDesc());
        myHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(models.get(i).getIcon()); // here we used imge resource

        myHolder.setItemCLickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {

                String gTitle = models.get(position).getTitle();
                String gDesc = models.get(position).getDesc();
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)myHolder.mImageView.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

                //get our data with intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AnotherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("actionBarTitle", filterList.get(position).getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("brandNewDesc", filterList.get(position).getBrandNewDesc());
                intent.putExtra("iImage", bytes);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



   }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        if (filter == null){
            filter = new CustomFilter(filterList, this);
        }

        return filter;
    }
}
```

**This is the Custom Filter**

```js
public class CustomFilter extends Filter {

    ArrayList<Model> filterList;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    public CustomFilter(ArrayList<Model> filterList, MyAdapter adapter) {
        this.filterList = filterList;
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraints) {


        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

        if (constraints != null && constraints.length() >0){

            constraints = constraints.toString().toUpperCase();

            ArrayList<Model> filterModels = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filterList.size(); i++){
                if (filterList.get(i).getTitle().toUpperCase().contains(constraints)){
                    filterModels.add(filterList.get(i));
                }
            }

            filterResults.count = filterModels.size();
            filterResults.values = filterModels;
        }

        else {
            filterResults.count = filterList.size();
            filterResults.values = filterList;
        }

        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

        adapter.models = (ArrayList<Model>) filterResults.values;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After serious hardwork, have i come to share the solution with happiness.
It was all my mistake. I forgot to call the initials of Model while sending the description text through the use of intent.

**The answer below solved it: I can see the accurate search title and its respective description in AnotherActivity**

```js
ArrayList<Model> models;
intent.putExtra("brandNewDesc", models.get(position).getBrandNewDesc());
```